# how to sovle permission of access in php

Tags: php, html

**Here is an 403 appear.how to fix it.**

Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /babytradeshopapps/select * from overall where LoginID = baby on this server.

Apache/2.2.8 (Win32) PHP/5.2.6 Server at localhost Port 80

```
$con1 = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","root","password");

  mysql_select_db("babytradeapps");

  $sql1 = "Select LoginID , Password , Permission
          from loginacc where Permission = 2 ";


  $results = mysql_query($sql1,$con1);

   echo "<tr><th>mebac</th></tr>";

  echo "<table border=5 cellpadding=10>";

  echo "<tr><th>ac</th><th>p</th><th>per</th></tr>";

  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) { 

   echo "<tr><td><form name='form' method='post' action='select * from overall where LoginID = {$row[0]}'><input type='submit' name='button' value='view' /></form></td><td><input type=text id='row0' name='row0' value='$row[0]' /></td><td><input type=text id='row1' name='row1' value='$row[1]' /></td>
              <td><input type=text id='row2' name='row2' value='$row[2]' /></td><td><input type='submit' name='button' value='change' /></td></tr>";

  }

  echo "</table>";
```

Comment: What in the world is this? `/babytradeshopapps/select * from overall where LoginID = baby`

Comment: Setting your form action to a SQL query is not going to work, it needs to be a page that makes a query. What are you trying to achieve with that?

Comment: And if you're getting a `403` for that absurd URL, it was probably `mod_security` which blocked it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering why your address doesn't contain a file extension within the url. Usually you call such simple scripts by `http://localhost/babytradeshopapps/my-script.php`.

Whatever, the error code 403 means that you don't have permission to access the script file or even directory. Change the permissions to readable by the webserver and try again.